# CORS set to allow all but preflight still fails

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, cors

I am using Istio in Google Kubernetes Engine with Istio. I've added a CORS policy to my virtual service that allows all origins. It looks like this:

```
  - match:
    - port: 443
    route:
    - destination:
        host: rev79-api-service
        port:
          number: 9000
    corsPolicy:
      allowOrigin:
        - '*'
      allowMethods:
        - POST
        - GET
        - OPTIONS
        - PUT
        - DELETE
      allowHeaders:
        - grpc-timeout
        - content-type
        - keep-alive
        - user-agent
        - cache-control
        - content-type
        - content-transfer-encoding
        - x-accept-content-transfer-encoding
        - x-accept-response-streaming
        - x-user-agent
        - x-grpc-web
      maxAge: 86400s
      exposeHeaders:
        - grpc-status
        - grpc-message
      allowCredentials: true
```

But When I try to make a request from a browser I get this error:

> dev.rev79.app/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://api.rev79.app/sil.rev79.Admin/ListNations' from origin
>   'https://dev.rev79.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
>   HTTP ok status.

What am I supposed to do to avoid this CORS error?

I'm considering directing all requests with method `OPTIONS` to a service that just gives a 200 response (i.e. my health check path) but I think there must be a more conventional approach.

Comment: could you find a solution for your issue? There is a [similar issue on Istio forum](https://discuss.istio.io/t/setting-access-control-allow-origin/6392).

Comment: I gave up on trying to use Istio